# To find mistake in the calculation of number of surjections from a set with $4$ elements to a set with $3$ elements

Tags: combinatorics

A problem says:

> Find the number of surjective maps from a set with $4$ elements to a
> set with $3$ elements.

I attempted the problem in following way.

Say given sets are $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$.
We have to count the onto maps from $A$ to $B$. This means every element of set $B$ must have preimage.
So, for $b_1$, there are $4$ possible pre-images, then for $b_2$, we are left with $3$ choices and for $b_3$, $2$ choices.
So we have $4\cdot 3\cdot 2=24$ ways to form onto functions.

But while searching the general formula for onto functions, I found that it is related to Stirling number and correct answer is $36$.

But I am unable to figure out the mistake in my argument.

Comment: since this is supposed to be a map you also have to define what the fourth element in A maps to (here you only ever defined the map for 3 elements)

Comment: @Lassadar Ok. Got it. Is there any way to correct my argument by adding some more details?

Comment: If $B$ had only one element would your argument give $4$ as the number of surjections from $A$ to $B$?

Comment: If the pre-image of $a_1$ is defined as the set of all elements that map to $a_1$ then there are $10$ possible pre-images, $4$ one-element sets and $6$ two-element sets.

Comment: The sort of answer to be given depends on what you have available. Stitling numbers? The in-and-out formula? Just common sense and brute force?

Comment: @Believer I would argue as follows: as the map has to be surjective, exactly two elements of  A map to the same element in B. There are ${4}\choose{2}$ ways of picking two that map to the same element. We can view those 2 as just one element which leaves us with the problem of mapping 3 elements onto 3 elements which can be done in $3!$ ways. -> ${{4}\choose{2}} 3! = 36$

Comment: The numbers being so small, you can do it this simple minded way. First decide which element of $B$ gets the extra pre-image. So $3\cdot\binom42\cdot2\cdot1=36$

Comment: Thank you both.